# Install Jekyll on Mac 10.11 without homebrew or sudo

Tags: macos, installation, ruby, jekyll

I tried to install [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) on my Mac *(OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan with Xcode cli tools installed)* using `gem install jekyll`, but I received this error:

> $ gem install jekyll
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>   You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

I furrowed my eyebrows and then read the [install troubleshooting docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#jekyll-amp-mac-os-x-1011) on the Jekyll site, which discuss [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) in El Capitan. I'm still feeling dissatisfied at this point.

I don't know anything about Ruby other than what I've read today, but I know a fair bit about bash. The developers suggest using `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin jekyll`. Is the `sudo` in this case only for if the folder permissions for `/usr/local/bin` require escalated privileges or is it for something else also?

Is there a way that I can install Jekyll

- without using `sudo` and
- without installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (or any other package installation tools / third-party software) and
- without modifying the permissions (`755` `root:wheel`) on my `/usr/local/` folder?

If so, what are the implications on the operation of Jekyll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can change your `$GEM_HOME`environment variable to a folder you have write and execute permissions to. Convention is to create a `.gem` folder in home. Then make sure and add that folder to your `$GEM_PATH` environment variable. Then you should be able to install gems to your hearts content AND use gems installed in the system gem folder.

References:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210012
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277228/203845

Comment: ✌️ Thanks for that. I did the equivalent of this for npm global installs and it's much nicer than using `/usr/local/`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach I found on [a relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3984#issuecomment-143300703) (from 25 Sep 2015) and am copying below the horizontal rule below. (Be sure to add the binary path to your `$PATH` via your `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/paths.d/`)

---

Have a few moments and want to reiterate, and re-share-- in a summary format, that installing `jekyll` (`gems` in general) by leveraging the `gem` executable capabilities to isolate ruby gem installations works out of box with OS X 10.11 for example with [only] the following, with the added benefit of leaving the system completely alone, and isolating `jekyll` and its dependencies to the current user/group [only]:

> OS X XCode Command Line Utilities
>
> > Can be installed via calling a developer command such as `git` and following prompts.
>
> With OS X' native `ruby` and `gem`:
>
> > ```
> > gem install --user-install --bindir ~/bin --no-document --pre --verbose jekyll
> > ```
>
> ```
> export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
> ```

```
$ jekyll --version
jekyll 3.0.0.pre.beta9

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

If System-wide meddling with a tinker-hostile environment is not your interest, and or you don't want/need custom/specific Ruby environment(s) (`rbenv`, `chruby`, `RVM`, ...), then a --user-install approach may be worth considering. And it works with stock OS X (`10.11 currently`).